# The definition of the determinant of a coherent sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $ X $ be a smooth (projective) variety and $ \mathcal{F} $ a torsion-free coherent sheaf of rank $ r $ on $ X $. The determinant $ \det \mathcal{F} $ can be defined by

(1) $ \det \mathcal F := ( \wedge^r \mathcal{F} )^{\vee \vee} $. Here the double dual denotes the reflexive hull of the rank $ 1 $ sheaf $ \wedge^r \mathcal{F} $ and therefore is a line bundle (as $ X $ is smooth).

(2) $ \det \mathcal F := \bigotimes_j (-1)^j \det E^j $ for a finite length resolution $ E^{\bullet} $ of $ \mathcal{F} $ by locally free sheaves. Here the notation $ (-1)^j \det E^j $ just means $ \det E^j $ for even $ j $ and $ (\det E^j)^{\vee} $ for odd $ j $. The determinant computed this way can be shown to be independent of the chosen complex $ E^{\bullet} $.

Are these two definitions the same? And if yes, why? I have been going crazy over this point!

Comment: Restrict over the maximal open on which the coherent sheaf is locally free.

Comment: @JasonStarr Oh wow. This maximal open set U will have complement codimension 2 or larger - because the local ring at the generic point of a codimension 1 subvariety is of dimension 1 hence a DVR so torsion-free stalk of F is the same as free stalk of F there. Now on that maximal open set, the definitions of det agree and the restriction Pic X to Pic U is an isomorphism because of codimension >=2 again. Correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.